# Universal change of coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Suppose the bijective linear transformation $T_1$ maps the elements of the subspace $X$, to the subspace $X_1$. Similarly, the linear transformation $T_2$ maps elements of $X$ to $T_2$. An illustration is :
[image]

Now, my question is, **can we find a transformation that takes any elements in $X_1$ or $X_2$ and map back it to $X$**?

More specifically, assume for $x \in X$ , we have $T_1 x = x_1, x_1 \in X_1$ and $T_2 x = x_2, x_2 \in X_2$ . My goeal is to find a transformation $T$ such that for the mentioned $x, x_1, x_2$, $Tx_1 = T x_2 = x, ~ x \in X$.

Comment: The illustration is not seen. Are $T_1$ and $T_2$ supposed to be surjective?

Comment: the illustration is an image: https://mermaid.ink/img/eyJjb2RlIjoiZ3JhcGggVERcbiAgQVtYXSAtLT58VF8xfCBCKFhfMSlcbiAgQVtYXSAtLT58VF8yfCBDKFhfMilcbiIsIm1lcm1haWQiOnsidGhlbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0In0sInVwZGF0ZUVkaXRvciI6ZmFsc2V9

Comment: also, $$T_1, T_2$$  are bijective.

Comment: You should state then in the question body that they're bijective. But then they have well defined inverse mappings ${T_1}^{-1}:X_1\to X$ and ${T_2}^{-1}:X_2\to X$, which are also linear. Are you looking for these?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited the question with more details. As you can see, I'm looking for an inverse mapping from the union of $X_1$ and $X_2$

Comment: Ummm, I have a feeling that, this is trivial, hear me out please. If we calculate $T_1^{-1} x_1,T_2^{-1} x_1,T_1^{-1} x_2,T_2^{-1} x_2$, Then two of these are equal (since bijection is injective and surjective) and gives you the answer. Is there a computational limitation?, In other words, it all boils down to the a priori knowledge that $x_1$ is generated using $T_1$ and $x_2$ is generated using $T_2$, do $X_1$ and $X_2$ overlap with each other? If $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$ then it would be much easy.

Comment: I didn't understand. Assume $T_1$ is 45 degree clock-wise rotation and $T_2$ is 90 degree counter clock-wise rotation. Then $T_1^{-1} x_1 = x = T_2^{-1} x_2$  but the others are not the same. The assumption is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have overlaps.